# How to serialize boolean as String in Spring Boot Rest response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Recently I have migrated the project from Jersey to Spring Rest. Previously boolean field was serialized as String like `success: "true"`, now it became without quotes `success: true`. It wouldn't be a problem but old apps rely on it and can't deserialize. How to return boolean values as String in Spring Boot? Any `spring.jackson.serialization` property?

Comment: Why don't you just use Boolean.toString?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't have access to this field,  create a class which will do serialization for it:

```
public class StringBooleanSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Boolean bool, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        generator.writeString(bool ? "true" : "false");
    }
}
```

Register it with your object mapper:

```
    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
    simpleModule.addSerializer(new StringBooleanSerializer());

    objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
```

That's it. However if you have access to this field you can do just this:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=StringBooleanSerializer.class)
private Boolean bool;
```

The same goes with deserialization if necessary.

Comment: It didn't work until I added serializer for primitive boolean. I've edited your answer with full config.

Comment: simpleModule.addSerializer(Boolean.class, new StringBooleanSerializer());
simpleModule.addSerializer(boolean.class, new StringBooleanSerializer());

Answer (score 0):

Write your custom serializer and deserializer and use following annotations on that boolean field:

@JsonSerialize and @JsonDeserialize.